# Issue getting arrays in JavaScript to work TypeError: Cannot set property

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

Error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined`

relevant code:

```
var field = new Array(6);
for(var x=0; x<field.length; x++){
  field[x] = new Array(12);
  for(var y=0; y<field[x].length; y++){
    field[x][y]= new tile();
    field[x][y].type = Math.floor(Math.random()*7);
    field[x][y].subtype[0]=false;//error happens when I run this line
    field[x][y].subtype[1]=false;
    field[x][y].subtype[2]=false;
    field[x][y].subtype[3]=false;
  }
}


function tile() {
  var type = 0; type = 0;//int
  var subtype = new Array(4);//Boolean

//+ some functions
}
```

I know that I am missing something, but I don't know what. Any help?

edit: also, when I added "this." before 'type' and 'subtype' in the tile object, I got 
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this 
edit#2: I got that error because I typed

```
var this.
//instead of
this.
```

Comment: What do you expect: `var type = 0; type = 0;` to do? You do realize the `var` declaration is already setting the value to `0`.

Comment: By convention, functions used as constructors have a name that starts with a capital letter, so `... = new Tile();` stands out more.

Comment: To izuriel: It fixed this issue when I was working with just type, but the same method could not be applied to subType. /n To RobG: thank you for telling me, this is my first "teach yourself js" project, and pointers on convention are very good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set your `tile` properties as just that, *member properties* by prefixing them with the `this` keyword, ie

```
function tile() {
    this.type = 0;
    this.subtype = new Array(4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a comment:

To save a lot of typing, you might consider something like:

```
for(var y=0; y<field[x].length; y++){
  field[x].push(new Tile(Math.floor(Math.random()*7)));
}
```

and in the constructor:

```
function Tile(type, subtypes) {
  this.type = type;
  this.subtype = subtypes || [false,false,false,false];
}
```

so that a new *Tile* can be initilised with values passed in the call or set to defaults if not.

Comment: The first suggestion sounds good, but will I later be able to refer to individual tiles as field[x][y]? The second suggestion is impracticable, as the code that I posted is to create a scenario that would otherwise be created by logic in the Tile object, but not at initialization. This is only so that I can see how they will act while designing the engine. how does the first suggestion work, so that I might use it later?

Comment: @user3483402—in regard to "...able to refer to individual tiles..", yes. It builds exactly the same structure, it just doesn't use *y*. In regard to the initialiser, it allows passing the "subtype" array when calling the constructor, e.g. `new Tile(type, [false,false,false,false])` so you can generate the subtype array however and assign it later. If you can't do that, keep going as you are. :-)